# how to open windows form in panel from the another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with windows form ASP.net C#

I have panel1 in which I am opening a form named form1.

form1 has a button. On this button clicke I want to close the form1 and open the new form named form2 in the same panel1

I have opened the form1 in panel1 as follows

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Visible = true;
```

Please help

Comment: Did you try anything yet ? Where are you having a problem ? Can you post some code ?

Answer (score 3):

First - I suggest you to use [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx), which are supposed to be used as reusable containers of other controls. [Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) are supposed to represent windows. So, usage of form as a controls container hosted on another window is not very good idea. If you need to have ability to show same data both in your panel and in separate window, then use same user control both on your form with panel and on Form1.

So, with user control. Adding them to panel is really simple:

```
UserControl1 control1 = new UserControl1();
control1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
control1.SomethingHappened += UserControl1_SomethingHappened; // see below
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Controls.Add(control1);
```

To have ability to switch user controls you can add event to `UserControl1` and raise it when button is clicked:

```
// UserControl1 code
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingHappened != null) // notify listeners, if any
       SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then handle this event on your main form:

```
// MainForm code
private void UserControl1_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 control1 = (UserControl1)sender;
    sender.SomethingHappened -= UserControl1_SomethingHappened;

    UserControl2 control2 = new UserControl2();
    control2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    panel1.Controls.Add(control2);
}
```